# How to make first line in a CSS list share a gradient color animation?

Tags: html, css

I am coding a startpage for my personal use and adding some interesting effects I found to enjoy..

Currently the page looks like this:

Startpage Only name:

[image]

I am looking into changing the category colours to use the following gradient animation, shared between the columns

> 

```css
html {
  background-color: #191919;
  font-family: "Atkinson Hyperlegible";
  font-size: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gradient {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(180, 142, 173, 1) 0%, rgba(191, 97, 106, 1) 12.5%, rgba(208, 135, 112, 1) 25%, rgba(235, 203, 139, 1) 37.5%, rgba(163, 190, 140, 1) 50%, rgba(235, 203, 139, 1) 62.5%, rgba(208, 135, 112, 1) 75%, rgba(191, 97, 106, 1) 87.5%, rgba(180, 142, 173, 1) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(180, 142, 173, 1) 0%, rgba(191, 97, 106, 1) 12.5%, rgba(208, 135, 112, 1) 25%, rgba(235, 203, 139, 1) 37.5%, rgba(163, 190, 140, 1) 50%, rgba(235, 203, 139, 1) 62.5%, rgba(208, 135, 112, 1) 75%, rgba(191, 97, 106, 1) 87.5%, rgba(180, 142, 173, 1) 100%);
  background-position: 0px;
  background-size: 1000px;
  background-repeat: round;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: background 4s ease-in-out 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes background {
  from {
    background-position: 0px
  }
  to {
    background-position: 960px
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class=gradient><span>>subject05</span></p>

  <body>
```

I managed to do this:

Startpage gradient columns:

[image]

But my solution hides the other column item's visibility.

Basically I just added class=gradient to 
*The full code will be at the bottom*

Turning the text clip off generates site like this:

Text clip off:

[image]

**Full page code**

```css
  html {
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #191919;
      color: #c5c8c6;
      display: flex;
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      user-select: none;
    }

    body {

      font-family: "Atkinson Hyperlegible";
      font-size: 30px;
      background-color: #191919;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-height: 30ch;
      min-width: 50vw;
      padding: 2em;
    }

    p {
      font-weight: bold;
    }


    a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      background-color:transparent;
      transition: bottom: 1s;
      transition-timing-function: ease;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: #999999;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;

      margin: 4;
      padding: 8px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 10px #121212 0 inset ;
      border-radius: 16px;
      transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
      border-color: #FFF 0;
}
  ul:hover{
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 10px #121212;

}
    span {
      display: inline-block;
      color: inherit;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 10px #121212 0 inset ;
      border-radius: 16px;
      transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
      border-color: #FFF 0;
      padding: 8px ;
}

  span:hover {
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 10px #121212;
  }
.gradient {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(180,142,173,1) 0%, rgba(191,97,106,1) 12.5%, rgba(208,135,112,1) 25%, rgba(235,203,139,1) 37.5%, rgba(163,190,140,1) 50%, rgba(235,203,139,1) 62.5%, rgba(208,135,112,1) 75%, rgba(191,97,106,1) 87.5%, rgba(180,142,173,1) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(180,142,173,1) 0%, rgba(191,97,106,1) 12.5%, rgba(208,135,112,1) 25%, rgba(235,203,139,1) 37.5%, rgba(163,190,140,1) 50%, rgba(235,203,139,1) 62.5%, rgba(208,135,112,1) 75%, rgba(191,97,106,1) 87.5%, rgba(180,142,173,1) 100%);
  background-position: 0px;
  background-size: 1000px;
  background-repeat: round;
  -webkit-background-clip:text ;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: background 4s ease-in-out 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@keyframes background{
  from {background-position: 0px}
  to {background-position: 960px}
}



    nav {
      column-gap: 2em;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
      padding: 0 0;
    }

    ul:nth-child(1n) li:first-child {
      color: #a54242;
    }

    ul:nth-child(2n) li:first-child {
      color: #de935f;
    }

    ul:nth-child(3n) li:first-child {
      color: #f0c674;
    }

    ul:nth-child(4n) li:first-child {
      color: #8c9440;
    }

    ul:nth-child(5n) li:first-child {
      color: #85678f;
    }

    li:first-child {
      font-weight: bold;

    li:first-child {
      font-weight: bold;

    }
```

```html
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <title>New Tab</title>
  <style>
    html {  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p class=gradient><span>>subject05</span></p>

  <nav>

    <ul>
      <li>general</li>
      <li><a href="https://gsobrance.edupage.org/user/">school</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/">steam</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.messenger.com/">messenger</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>entertainment</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">youtube</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://music.youtube.com/">music</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com/">reddit</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.pirateproxy.space/">pirate bay</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://1337x.to/">1377x</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>misc</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.gmail.com/">gmail</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://ymovie.streamcinema.cz/">cinema</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://monkeytype.com//">type monkey</a></li>
  </ul>

  </nav>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Also forgot to mention I used this as a base: https://github.com/midnitefox/Nord-Theme-Ports-and-Assets/tree/main/custom-start-page

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand your question properly. You already have the first item in the list as a gradient. Would you mind explaining again?

Comment: Sorry, could access the pc, but A guy on Reddit solved the issue [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/startpages/comments/pd5k4d/i_need_help_with_the_css_code_of_my_site_anyone/hanymby?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 0):

[Reddit Helper](https://www.reddit.com/r/startpages/comments/pd5k4d/i_need_help_with_the_css_code_of_my_site_anyone/hanymby?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

calvinchd

> "I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve. But if you want the first items in the list to have a synced background animation (eg. The background scrolls from the leftmost item ("general" and "subject05") to the rightmost "misc" )."

I think you should put your body inside a div using the gradient class.

```
<body>
<div class="gradient">
    <p><span>subject05</span></p>

    <!--...Rest of your current body content...-->
    
    </nav>
</div>
```

and add this to the css.

```
  ul li:not(:first-child) {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
  text-fill-color: initial; /* I don't think text-fill-color is a thing but I left it in */
}
```